# Java Join multiple IRC Channel at once

Tags: java, irc, channel

I want to create an IRC bot which acts in multiple channels.

My question now is: How can I join multiple channels with one connection so that I can receive and send messages to these channels?

Comment: I kind of knew, that there would come an answer like this... How can I do it?

Comment: I doubt there are many willing souls on this site that will provide a much better answer. The less sarcastic ones will just ignore the question. I did answer the question to you. However that was not the question you wanted to ask. So please re ask the question, provide as much details as you can and there are a multitude of users here who would gladly help.

Comment: @Emz rewrote the Question

Comment: The same way you do 1 channel. You just send more join commands. The IRC protocol sends you all the channel messages interleaved.

Answer (score 0):

Are you implementing irc yourself or using some library?

At a protocol level you just send multiple join commands to join multiple channels. The incoming messages will be marked with what channel they are for. Read RFC1459 for full details.

If you are using a library you will have to look at the documentation of said library.

Answer (score 0):

I would work with [PircBot](http://www.jibble.org/pircbot.php) to make it easier for you. I'm using it for a Twitch bot.